Angular 18 read JSON file in assets folder
In angular 18, I have to read a json file using HTTP client. I cannot predict the hosted URL. The site may be hosted in two or three level sub folder domain names. How can I read the json files from correct path, using HTTP client get. I request for a sample code.

You can just add /assets/something.json to the get call.
getJson() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/something.json');
}

In this scenario, it will add automatically look in the assets of your project.
Make sure you have the folder added to the assets array of angular.json.
Reference Stackblitz
